# Unable to debug native using Sequoyah?

Tags: eclipse, android-ndk

I'm n00b to NDK
I used instruction from http://wiki.eclipse.org/Sequoyah
I'm using:
Eclipse: 3.7.2
NDK: r7b
Platform tools: 10
tools: 16
Sequoyah: http://download.eclipse.org/sequoyah/updates/2.0/

I'm just trying to debug hell-jni sample which comes with ndk, aim is to switch between java and C/C++, and debug both native and java code.
I'm getting error: Connection reset by peer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because the eclipse will start the gdb server, on the other hand, the ndk-gdb script will start the gdb server.

Solution is to find the ndk-gdb in your ndk dir, and comment out the last line 
like this: ## $GDBCLIENT -x `native_path $GDBSETUP`  save and it should be OK.

or copy/paste the ndk-gdb to ndk-gdb-eclipse, and make the same changes in ndk-gdb-eclipse, and tell eclipse to start gdb server using ndk-gdb-eclipse, via some portal in Debug Configurations=>C/C++ .